# Get HTML element with web scraping on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping

i´m trying to get the link of the video of this [page](https://www3.animeflv.net/ver/sword-art-online-alicization-war-of-underworld-20) with the package "web_scraper". I can find it using Chrome´s tools (is an attribute of a *jw-video jw-reset* element. The problem is that when you enter the page you can´t see this attribute before clicking in the play button. Can any one help me?

I have already this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_scraper/web_scraper.dart';

class Prueba extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new _Prueba();
}

class _Prueba extends State<Prueba> {

  final webScraper = WebScraper('https://www3.animeflv.net');

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> link;

  void fetchProducts() async {
    // Loads web page and downloads into local state of library
    if (await webScraper
        .loadWebPage('/ver/sword-art-online-alicization-war-of-underworld-20')) {
      setState(() {
        link = webScraper.getElement(
            'div.jw-wrapper.jw-reset > div.jw-media.jw-reset > video.jw-video.jw-reset', ['src']);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Requesting to fetch before UI drawing starts
    fetchProducts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
    print(link);
    return Container();
  }
}
```